# What's wrong with this Array? giving me Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in functions.php

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, foreach, redux-framework

I am developing Wordpress Theme, i am using Redux Framework for getting user options. I want to create widgets dynamically according to which category user selected. These widgets will be shown in the category page on specific category front end user selected.

Redux Framework is returning array having checked and non-checked categories. Checked categories has value of 1 and non-checked has values of 0

The following is the output when i `print_r($redcats)`

```
Array
(
    [14] => 1
    [13] => 1
    [7] => 0
    [1] => 1
)
```

In `header.php` when i run code only to extract indexes which contain value of 1, code run perfect and gives me what i want using `foreach() loop` so that i can get category name and category slug later on as follows,

```
    $redcats = $mythemeslug['opt_extrac_widgets_selected'];
    foreach($redcats as $key=>$val)
    {
        if($val == 1)
        {
            echo "Category is ".returncatname1($key)." | and Slug is "
           .returncatslug1($key)."</br>";
        }
    }

    function returncatslug1($id)
    {
        $category = get_category( $id );
        return $category->slug;
    }

    function returncatname1($id)
    {
        $catname = get_cat_name($id);
        return $catname;
    }
```

The following is the output since i ran entire codes in `header.php` first to test if everything is working well:

```
Category is History | and Slug is history
Category is My Gossipz | and Slug is my-gossipz
Category is Uncategorized | and Slug is uncategorized
```

but when i place the same `foreach loop` in `functions.php` gives me an error

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\wp\wp-content\themes\**themename**\functions.php on line 111
```

where line 111 contains the following code.

```
$redcats = $mythemeslug['opt_extrac_widgets_selected'];
foreach($redcats as $key=>$val)
{
 //some codes comes in..
}
```

I wonder why i am getting `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\wp\wp-content\themes\**themename**\functions.php on line 111`
while in `header.php` when i run the same code give correct results..

Note that, `$mythemeslug['opt_extrac_widgets_selected']` is the Redux Framework returned results and i have other Redux Framework options already being manipulated in `functions.php` and they are working correctly

For reference: In Redux Framework options file, the code used to get categories is

```
array(
    'id'       => 'opt_extrac_widgets_selected',
    'type'     => 'checkbox',
    'title'    => 'Activate Category to have its own Widgets',
    'required' => array( 'opt_extrac_widgets_set', '=', '1' ),//depends on above option.
    'data'     => 'categories'
   ),
```

Comment: `$redcats` is a string, which has the values of `$mythemeslug['opt_extrac_widgets_selected']` in it (unless that element is a sub-array of `$mythemeslug`).

Comment: Why when i `print_r` gives me array, Please see the start of this post when i `print_r($redcats)` @Qirel

Comment: note not all variables/functions available at the header.php process will be available at the stage your functions.php process runs, you need to either hook your code to a later time or define the variable. If you var_dump in your functions file, you should see what it actually contains.

Comment: To prevent such warnings from appearing, take a look at [`is_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php), this way it's guaranteed that whatever you put in the `foreach` can be processed by it.

Comment: Inspect the contents of `$mythemeslug` at the point of execution (functions.php) - if you dont have a debugger that can set a breakpoint, then `var_dump($mythemeslug);` Edit your question with the output